# Angular UI Modal Shows Content On 2nd Open, not First

Tags: angularjs, three.js, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an Angular UI Modal that loads a three.js scene. My modal opens, however, the scene doesn't render until I close the Modal and open it again. After that, the scene is shown in the modal without issue until I close the browser. I am sure this is related to how I am calling the function and perhaps I need a small timeout. However, I would prefer to avoid timeouts and just ensure that that the function rendering my "box" happens after the modal is opened.

Here is my Modal template:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Box Preview</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

    <div id="webGL-container" width="500px">
    </div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ok()">Close</button>
</div>
```

Here is my Controller to run the function that creates the three.js scene in the "webGL-container" div:

```
$scope.boxPreview = function () {
// Execute three.js function to render 3D "box"
generate3D();
// Open Modal
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
templateUrl: 'templates/boxpreview.html',
controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
size: 'lg',
});
```

Here is my modal dependency for closing the modal:

```
appControllers.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }]);
```

Here is my three.js code:

```
var scene;
var camera;
var renderer;
var box;
var controls;
var newtexture;

// 3D OBJECT - Generate

function generate3D() {
//Instantiate a Collada loader
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load('https://myblob.net/dae.dae', function (collada) {

box = collada.scene;              
box.traverse(function (child) {                   
if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh) {                       
var animation = new THREE.Animation(child, child.geometry.animation);
                        animation.play();
}
});

box.scale.x = box.scale.y = box.scale.z = .2;
box.updateMatrix();

init();
animate();
});

function init() {
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);
//renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setSize(500, 500);

// Load the box file
scene.add(box);

// Lighting
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight();
scene.add(light);

// Camera
camera.position.x = 40;
camera.position.y = 40;
camera.position.z = 40;

camera.lookAt(scene.position);

// Rotation Controls
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
controls.zoomSpeed = 5;

controls.noZoom = false;
controls.noPan = false;

$("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
}
```

**Update 1:** I have noticed that when I don't use an external template, but rather create a template as follows, it loads. I would prefer to use an external template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Box Preview</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="webGL-container" width="500px">
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ok()">Close</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: You need to call the generate3D(); from the ModalInstanceCtrl

Comment: Hello. Can you post the generate3D file? It sounds like there's something running asynchronously and you're not handling it.

Comment: @AliAdravi -  how can I call the function across controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I moved my 3D box generation code into a dedicated controller and called it from the template I load into the Modal as follows:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Box Preview</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" data-ng-controller="appBoxDisplayCtrl">

    <div id="webGL-container" width="500px">
    </div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ok()">Close</button>
</div>
```